# OhMyZsh is not running the command associated with an alias

Tags: bash, alias, kubernetes-helm, oh-my-zsh

I want to delete a helm instance using an alias, to which I can append a named instance and this is added to the command and run.

I have the following in my .zshrc file

```
alias helmd='function __helmd() {echo "helm delete $* --tiller-namespace=this-is-for-stack-uat --purge"; unset -f __helmd; }; __helmd'
```

When I type

```
helmd delete-this-instance
```

I get

```
helm delete delete-this-instance --tiller-namespace=this-is-for-stack-uat --purge
```

Which is the expected output, however the helm delete command isnt run, instead it prints the string out and then shows the cursor so I can start typing commands. What I want it to do is run the function so that the instance is deleted.

Comment: The function you define in your alias just does an echo, so when you call the alias that's what happens.

Comment: what should I use instead of ```echo```, I have also tried ```printf``` and ```stdout```

Comment: To execute a command, just write the command. I don't understand the point of your alias that defines a function that will undefine itself when called then calls it, but assuming it has no point I'd just write the following in the .zshrc : `function helmd() { helm delete $* --tiller-namespace=this-is-for-stack-uat --purge; }` then call it as you were already doing.

Answer (score 0):

As @Aaron mentions, just run the command, don't echo it.

`alias helmd='function __helmd() {helm delete $* --tiller-namespace=this-is-for-stack-uat --purge; unset -f __helmd; }; __helmd'`